# How to calculate time in php

Tags: php

help me in calculating exact time with AM and PM

```
$time1 = strtotime(10:00); /// in pm 
$time1 = strtotime(08:00); ///// answer should come in am calculation
                                 is exact but not the am pm value
$count = date ('g:i ' ,strtotime($time1 . '+' . $time2));
```

My Problem is if i calculate time i calculate it correctly as i want but how can i set the PM and AM to time if i take 10:00 PM time add 4 hour to it now time is 02:00 AM how to get that AM PM value with time and any help with subtract time how we subtract time

Comment: `10:00` is always am. `22:00` is pm Also, you have a variable naming issue.

Comment: date and time functions are one of the best documented features of PHP... what have you tried so far?

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do, but I would highly recommend you look at using DateTime and related classes (like DateInterval).  These will help you greatly in working with dates and times.

Comment: Are you just trying to add eight hours to a specific date and time?

Comment: yes geting am pm value automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DateTime to deal with Dates and Times with less hassle.

```
<?php
$time = new DateTime("10am"); // assumes 10am today
$time->modify("+4 hours");
echo $time->format("g:i A"); // outputs 2:00 PM
```

See the [DateTime book](http://www.phparch.com/books/phparchitects-guide-to-date-and-time-programming/) by the author of the DateTime extension.

Comment: thanks for your 3 line code it helped me very well now i am able to add time and get the am pm vale which ever i want i have a question can i subtract time with it or not any hints                                                                                                                   <!-------------- THANKS ANYWAY -------------------->

Comment: Yes, you can subtract time with `$time->modify('-4 hours');` Almost any string that `strtotime()` can interpret is usable. Or you can use the `add` and `sub` methods but you have to specify the time intervals in a more specific format. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
$t1 = strtotime('10am'); // 1399910400 on the date this was written
$t2 = strtotime('8am'); // 1399903200 on the date this was written
```

But note that that you CANNOT just do `$t1 + $t2`. You'll actually be doing

```
$t3 = 1399910400 + 1399903200
$t3 = 2799813600
```

And the timestamp `2799813600` corresponds to Sep 21, 2058.

You need to do:

```
'8am' + 2 hours => '10am';
```

which is

```
$t3 = strtotime('8am') + 60 * 60 * 2;
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^---2hours
```

Comment: Adding and subtracting seconds will get you into trouble when dealing with leap years / seconds and daylight savings.